# Latex twoside appendix in oneside document

Tags: latex

I've created a onesided report document in latex. But after the \appendix command, Latex uses twosided layout. I can tell by fact that my odd numbered pages have black lines on top and below. Also the chapter name ie. (appendix A. This is my title) shows up on top of the odd numbered page. I can not find anything on this using google. Is there a way to force latex to use oneside page layout?

Comment: You might want to ask this on tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Use `\onecolumn` to start a new page in one column mode.
Ask tex.stackexchange.com for quick answers.